# Azure Data Factory Data Migration

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Not really sure this is an explicit question or just a query for input. I'm looking at Azure Data Factory to implement a data migration operation. What I'm trying to do is the following:

I have a No SQL DB with two collections. These collections are associated via a common property.
I have a MS SQL Server DB which has data that is related to the data within the No SQL DB Collections via an attribute/column.

One of the NoSQL DB collections will be updated on a regular basis, the other one on a not so often basis.

What I want to do is be able to prepare a Data Factory pipline that will grab the data from all 3 DB locations combine them based on the common attributes, which will result in a new dataset. Then from this dataset push the data wihin the dataset to another SQL Server DB.

I'm a bit unclear on how this is to be done within the data factory. There is a copy activity, but only works on a single dataset input so I can't use that directly. I see that there is a concept of data transformation activities that look like they are specific to massaging input datasets to produce new datasets, but I'm not clear on what ones would be relevant to the activity I am wanting to do.

I did find that there is a special activity called a Custom Activity that is in effect a user defined definition that can be developed to do whatever you want. This looks the closest to being able to do what I need, but I'm not sure if this is the most optimal solution.

On top of that I am also unclear about how the merging of the 3 data sources would work if the need to join data from the 3 different sources is required but do not know how you would do this if the datasets are just snapshots of the originating source data, leading me to think that the possibility of missing data occurring. I'm not sure if a concept of publishing some of the data someplace someplace would be required, but seems like it would in effect be maintaining two stores for the same data.

Any input on this would be helpful.

Comment: I think this is too broad to SO. Sounds like to need to employee an architect to design you a solution.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you are trying to do.
I don't know if you have experience with SSIS but what you are trying to do is fairly common for either of these integration tools.

```
Your ADF diagram should look something like:
1. You define your 3 Data Sources as ADF Datasets on top of a 
corresponding Linked service
2. Then you build a pipeline that brings information from SQL Server into a 
temporary Data Source (Azure Table for example)
3. Next you need to build 2 pipelines that will each take one of your NoSQL 
Dataset and run a function to update the temporary Data Source which is the ouput
4. Finally you can build a pipeline that will bring all your data from the 
temporary Data Source into your other SQL Server
```

Steps 2 and 3 could be switched depending on which source is the master.

ADF can run multiple tasks one after another or concurrently. Simply break down the task in logical jobs and you should have no problem coming up with a solution.